# Best way to detect these nouns?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

"Discovery" is a noun. Yet "discover" is a verb.
"Making" is a noun.  Yet "make" is a verb.

Both "discovery" and "making" sound like verbs, but they aren't.

What is the best way to spot these noun(s) that seem like verbs(s)?

Comment: Does they make sense with an article? ***The** discovery of America*, ***The** making of 'Gone with the Wind'*.

Answer (score 1):

A very broad question but I may try to get you my two cents.

There's another buddy called 'gerund!' So, in your *'making'* case, it's a *gerund* which is used as a noun [according to the dictionary here.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gerund)

However, to me, *discovery* does not *sound* as a verb; not sure how it does to you! There's no *guessing* or *technique* to spot noun/verb. It comes with a lot of reading and being on this platform! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look really far into it, "to discover" is a verb. "Discovery" is a noun, meaning "the incident during which one discovers something". "To make" is a verb, and "making" is part of a present tense construction (I don't know the exact name) of "to make". "Making" is also a noun, used almost exclusively in the phrase "the making of something" and is a synonym of "production". Finally, "make" is the present tense form of "to make" for the pronouns I, you, we, and they. "Make" is also a noun, used almost exclusively in the phrases "what is the make of something" (and this can be answered and rearranged), inquiring about the company that made it, and the idiomatic phrase "make and model", used often for cars and meaning "the brand and model of the product".

My way to get around this confusion would be: Whenever one learns a new verb, check to see if it has any nouns ssociated with it; in other words, try to 'noun the verb", or vice versa. Often, this allows one to remember many forms of words that mean nearly the same thing.